# Wordpress if(if_page) and page template not working

Tags: wordpress

I am stuggeling to get my wordpress enque script to work. Dont know what i'm doing wrong, tried a lot but nothing seems to work.

I have a page with tittle Ledenlijst, id = 69.
I want to enque only to that page. So i tried to add to functions.php :

```
// Funtion to include stylesheet for page ledenlijst.
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style')  );
}
// Function to add ledenlijst
function add_ledenlijst() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/ledenlijst.js', 
        array('jquery')
    );
}

if(is_page('ledenlijst') ){ // Only on ladenlijst page
echo "Page ledenlijst identified"; // debug
    // Register Stylesheet
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
    // Register ledenlijst script
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ledenlijst' );
}
```

For some reason it's not identified. I also tried:
if(is__page(69),
A have copied the default page, created pageLedenlijst.php in my child theme folder, applied that theme to this page and tried:
if(is_page_template('pageLedenlijst.php')

Nothing is working, the debug is not shown, the enque schript will not load.

Comment: Try adding the is_page() code in a function and call it in a hook such as the "wp_loaded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

You just have one function to enqueue and then you check if the page you are in is the page you wanna enqueue the script.

I think you are using a child theme and this script ( ledenlijst.js ) is in your child theme not in the parent theme, am I right? If yes is the answer you have to change `get_template_directory_uri()` for `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` because get_template_directory_uri() ( when in a context of child theme) it calls for the parent theme directory and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` refers to the child theme directory

```
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style')  );
    if( is_page( 69 ) ){
        wp_enqueue_script('your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/ledenlijst.js', array('jquery') );
    }
}
```

Resources:
[`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)
[`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Sorry for bad english

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. What i did, was i moved the 
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ledenlijst' ); To the page template. Now it's working but i think it's not a very neat solution. I think Anand has a point in case of the order.. sugggestions for a better solution whitch doesn't need a page template are welcome

Comment: @Anand I know `is_page` doesn't work on functions.php, but when used inside a functions that is hooked to a hook like `wp_enqueue_scripts` that is hooked to `wp_head` and in that point it already knows what page has been loaded it works. I just didn't understand why would you downvote this if in that point of code it works.

Comment: @user2886088 what happened when you tested the code? Any error? Anything on console? Is this just a page? a front page? home?

Comment: @MarcosRodrigues so basically take the function you've provided above and hook it to wp_head and it will work?

Comment: @Anand No, you hook it to the 'wp_enqueue_scripts hook. 
You understand the concept of actions and filters (hook), right?
A hook is nothing more than a function that executes in certain points of a code. When you hook you tell your function to be executed in that part of the code. When you hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` your script is going to run where that hook is executed, but wp_enqueue_scripts is called in the by the wp_head hook, so when you hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` its automatically being called in `wp_head` hook, so your scripts are called where `wp_head()` is.

Comment: Sorry, not that easy to explain without examples and my english doesn't help very much. but if you want a better explanation I can write it better and with examples so it would be easier to understand. =)

Comment: Oh Yeah! I'm working now, later at night, I'll try to write something and paste a gist or something and some references in case you wanna know more about it.

Comment: On a second thought it wouldn't be necessary, I was testing my code on a Woocommerce page and the hook wasn't working. Tested the code on another page and it works, learned something. Thank you. Now onto investigating why the code doesn't work on a Woocommerce page :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marcos,
It worked indeed. I tried it again, forgot to change the get_template_directory_uri().

This code works:

```
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style')  );
    if( is_page( 69 ) ){
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/ledenlijst.js', array('jquery') );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

No need for a custom page / template anymore. Happy wwith the solution!

Comment: =) Happy to help. Modified my answer based on your response here